# How to filter ble devices by name using regex?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a ble project. I need to display the available devices which has "kdd_" in the beginning. I'm not much familiar with regex. Anyone knows how to filter devices using regex? Any other possible solution for filtering devices is also fine. I have attached the code for ble scan code below.

```
final BluetoothLeScannerCompat scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
        final ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setLegacy(false)
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).setReportDelay(1000).setUseHardwareBatchingIfSupported(false).build();
        final List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().build());
        scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback);
```

Comment: You probably can't. At least not with the `ScanFilter`s, you can only manually filter the data / search results after retrieval and manually apply the regex filter.

Comment: we can filter using ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName("regex").build(). What I'm asking is, how to pass regex in setDeviceName() function.

Comment: I know. Answer: you can't.

Comment: see my answer for more details as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr **You can't**.

Longer answer: The [`ScanFilter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.java) does list a couple of attributes that can be filtered, among others *"Name of remote Bluetooth LE device."*

If you look at the `public boolean matches(ScanResult scanResult)` method you can see

```
// Local name match.
if (mDeviceName != null && !mDeviceName.equals(scanRecord.getDeviceName())) {
    return false;
}
```

aka if you want to filter on the name you can only do a full name match. For other fields there are partial matches possible, but they are then compared using e.g. `BitUtils.maskedEquals`, not any regex logic.

You cannot subclass the `ScanFilter` to create your own filter logic because the class is `final`.

That means the logic is not there and you cannot add it => you cannot filter based on regex.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'll do the filtering while displaying.